# Display scrolling text message

Tags: javascript, scroll

I would like to use a java script to scroll a text message on a webpage: 
This is the code I use but it doesn't scroll; could someone help me?

Here is the link to jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mandolino/TkE3W/6/

```
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">

 msg = "ALL WEB free, free web directory ";
 msg += "con motore di ricerca. ";
 pos = 0;
 function ScrollMessage() {
 var newtext = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos);
 var div = document.getElementById("scroll");
 div.firstChild.nodeValue = newtext;
 pos++;
 if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0;
 window.setTimeout("ScrollMessage()",150);
 }

 ScrollMessage();
 </script>
 </head> 

<body onload="avvia()"> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using undefined function avvia() and your body element is broken..
Also the setTimeout's first parameter has to be the callback function itself, not a code to be evaluated..

I repaired it here: http://jsfiddle.net/TkE3W/7/

Comment: Thank you very much. Shall I use BODY ONLOAD?

Comment: I suggest you to use jquery and put your code into $(document).ready() function..

Comment: would you mind to suggest to me a jquery collections to be used? I am e begineer and I don't be able to do that. Thank you